# How to get the intersecting polygon of two polygons in python with numba supported external libraries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numba

I have made a polygon class that I use in a lot of my projects that has some functions. This class implements the separating axis theorem in numpy which detects collisions just fine.

However, I don't know how to get the shape created by the collision area which I want so I can combine these two colliding polygons. Here's a simplified version of my class.

```
class Polygon:
    def __init__(self, points: np.ndarray):
       self._points = points  # 1d array, points are [x, y, x, y, x, y]

    def get_corners(self):
       return np.reshape(self._points, (-1, 2))

    def intersection(self, poly: 'Polygon') -> bool:
        vertices_a = self.get_corners()
        vertices_b = poly.get_corners()

        edges_a = np.roll(vertices_a - np.roll(vertices_a.copy(), 2), -2)
        edges_b = np.roll(vertices_b - np.roll(vertices_b.copy(), 2), -2)

        edges = np.append(edges_a, edges_b, 0)

        axes = edges[::-1].copy()
        axes[:, 1] *= -1

        norm = np.sqrt(axes[:, 0] ** 2 + axes[:, 1] ** 2)

        axes[:, 0] = axes[:, 0] / norm
        axes[:, 1] = axes[:, 1] / norm

        for i in range(len(axes)):
            projection_a = np.dot(vertices_a, axes[i])
            projection_b = np.dot(vertices_b, axes[i])

            a_min = np.min(projection_a)
            a_max = np.max(projection_a)

            b_min = np.min(projection_b)
            b_max = np.max(projection_b)

            if (b_min > a_min or a_min > b_max) and (b_min > a_max or a_max > b_max) and \
                    (a_min > b_min or b_min > a_max) and (a_min > b_max or b_max > a_max):
                return False

        return True
```

I want to be able to do this in numpy so I can use this implementation with numba so no third party libraries unless they are compatible with numba. I tried using Shapely but unfortunately it doesn't work with numba.

Comment: I'm a bit confused because you say you want to do this without external libraries, but at the same time you say you want to do this with NumPy, which is an external library. And you tried Shapely which is also an external library. And Numba as well.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Sorry for the confusion, I am not against the use of external libraries I just can't use most of them with numba. I will edit the post to make that more clear!

Comment: Are the polygons convex or concave? It is a bit more complex with concave ones.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Let's assume they are convex since for most use cases that'll be more then enough. I know that the separating axis theorem only works with convex polygons too so it should be good enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the method more *numpythonic* avoiding loops:

```
def intersection(self, poly: 'Polygon') -> bool:

    vertices_a = self.get_corners()
    vertices_b = poly.get_corners()

    edges_a = np.roll(vertices_a - np.roll(vertices_a, 2), -2)
    edges_b = np.roll(vertices_b - np.roll(vertices_b, 2), -2)

    edges = np.append(edges_a, edges_b, 0)

    axes = edges[::-1].copy()
    axes[:, 1] = -axes[:, 1]
    axes /= np.linalg.norm(axes, axis=1, keepdims=True)

    proj_a = axes @ vertices_a.T
    proj_b = axes @ vertices_b.T

    a_min = proj_a.min(axis=1)
    a_max = proj_a.max(axis=1)
    b_min = proj_b.min(axis=1)
    b_max = proj_b.max(axis=1)

    return not (((b_min > a_min) | (a_min > b_max)) &
                ((b_min > a_max) | (a_max > b_max)) &
                ((a_min > b_min) | (b_min > a_max)) &
                ((a_min > b_max) | (b_max > a_max))).any()
```

Some superficial tests:

```
>>> a = Polygon(np.array([(0, 0),(10, 0),(10,10),(0,10)], dtype=float))
>>> b = Polygon(np.array([(5, 5),(15, 5),(15,15),(5,15)], dtype=float))
>>> c = Polygon(np.array([(5,15),(15,15),(15,25),(5,25)], dtype=float))
>>> a.intersection(b)
True
>>> a.intersection(c)
False
>>> b.intersection(c)
True
```

---

Edited after comments:

But checking for intersection is far easier than obtaining the polygon resulting from the intersection (or union). There are a number of methods around and you can start with the [Sutherland–Hodgman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman_algorithm) (more methods linked in the same Wikipedia article).

I worked on a geometry library where I used [Binary Space Partition (BSP) trees](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/bspfaq/index.html#12.txt) for polyhedron clipping. There's a really nice implementation (in Javascript) [here](https://github.com/evanw/csg.js/).

As long as 3D clipping also involves polygon clipping, I eventually deleted my original polygon clipping algorithm and applied the same BSP machinery.

By the way, Shapely never passed all my tests.

Comment: I do agree that this is a better approach because it removes the for loop, but I am not sure how this answers my original question? Just to clarify, I asked how do I get the polygon created where the two others intersect. Thank you for your responds!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok that seems to be what I was looking for! I do however hope there might be a better way of combining polygons then my approach I came up with? Basically my idea was get the intersecting shape created, remove any points inside the two parent polygons, and if there's any overlapping points only leave one. So basically is there a better way to go about combining two polygons I know are colliding since this seems inefficient?

Comment: Ah after looking through your links I think BSP is what I want